# Is it Possible to create a Queue for HashMap set?

Tags: java, data-structures, collections, queue, hashmap

Right now I am trying to create a producer/consumer thread, the producer thread goes through all possible combinations of letters and creates their respective MD5 hashes. Then each combination and its hash is put into the `HashMap<String,String>`. Now in my consumer thread I want to be able to use the `Queue<>` collection on the hashmap so my consumer thread may call `poll()` etc thus removing values atc like a `Queue` but still giving me the capability of seeing both the combination and its hash when calling `poll()` How would I go about doing this? I have the `HashMap` but dont know how to 'make' or cast it as a Queue. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should not use a HashMap without handling the thread-safety of your code. Else, you may end with a Live-lock.

To be able to iterate your Map with the order in which keys were inserted, you can use a LinkedHashMap.

```
Map m = Collections.synchronizedMap(new LinkedHashMap(...));
```

The producer would push entries like this (nothing special):

```
m.put(key, object)
```

The consumer would poll entries like this:

```
while (someCondition) {
    Map.Entry nextEntry = null;

    // This block is equivalent to polling
    {
         synchronized(s) {
             Iterator i = s.iterator(); // Must be in the synchronized block
             if (i.hasNext()) {
                 nextEntry  = i.next();
                 i.remove();
             }
         }
    }

    if (nextEntry != null) {
         // Process the entry
         ...
    } else {
         // Sleep for some time
         ...
    }
    // process
}
```

Comment: Thank you this worked a charm and was quick, easy and clear to implement

Answer (score 11):

The **[`LinkedHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html)** type is like a combination of a `HashMap` and a `Queue` - it stores key/value pairs, but also remembers the order in which they were inserted.  This might be exactly the type you're looking for.  There is no explicit `poll()` function, but if you get an iterator over the `LinkedHashMap` you will visit the elements in the order in which they were added.  You could probably then write a function like this:

```
public <KeyType, ValueType> KeyType first(LinkedHashMap<KeyType, ValueType> map) {
    assert !map.isEmpty();
    return map.iterator().next();
}
```

which will give you back the first element.  Just make sure to synchronize appropriately.

Alternatively, you could consider just storing key/value pairs inside a `Queue` by defining a helper class `Pair` and then storing `Pair`s in the queue.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Nice, so he will just need some SyncObject to signal when it is possible to read from LinkedHashMap at the consumer side.

Comment: Hi, LinkedHashMap is not thread-safe and it's not of type Queue.

Comment: @sperumal- I never insinuated that either of these were the case.  I assumed that the OP would supply the synchronization code.  Also, I don't believe that there is any requirement that it must be of type `Queue`; the OP's question never mentions this.  If this is a requirement, then this approach definitely will not work.

Comment: Thank you this does seem like the perfect solution but what more would I need to make to make it thread safe? would adding the volatile modifier to the LinkedHashMap be enough?

Comment: @DavidKroukamp- There are many ways to do this, but adding `volatile` would not do this.  You would need to synchronize access to the `LinkedHashMap`; perhaps by explicitly synchronizing on it, or perhaps by using something like a `Semaphore`.

Comment: Well it sounds like the most viable option. Thank you again

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you create a Queue of EntrySet -

```
Queue<EntrySet<String,String>> queue = new SynchronousQueue<EntrySet<String,String>>();
for (EntrySet<String,String> entry:map.entrySet()) {
   queue.add(entry);
}
```

You can consider using another type of queue, which lets you put the elements, and only the prdocuer waits in case of non empty such as [LinkedBlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html). 
The producer will then be able to recompose a map based on the EntrySet objects, if needed.

Comment: Hmm this seems like a good method. Thank you I will give it a try. One question those is this thread safe?

Comment: May be Queue<Map.Entry<String,String>>?